# Python - Web Scraping for Walmart

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to get some datas from [Walmart](https://www.walmart.com) using Python and BeautifulSoup `bs4`.

Simply I wrote a code for get the all category names and that works:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

baseurl = 'https://www.walmart.com/'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36'
}

r = requests.get('https://www.walmart.com/all-departments')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

sub_list = soup.find_all('div', class_='alldeps-DepartmentNav-link-wrapper display-inline-block u-size-1-3')

print(sub_list)
```

The problem is; when I try to get the values from this [link](https://www.walmart.com/browse/snacks-cookies-chips/cookies/976759_976787_1001391) by using the code below, I get empty results:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

baseurl = 'https://www.walmart.com/'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36'
}

r = requests.get('https://www.walmart.com/browse/snacks-cookies-chips/cookies/976759_976787_1001391')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

general_list = soup.find_all('a', class_='product-title-link line-clamp line-clamp-2 truncate-title')

print(general_list)
```

As I searched on old docs, I see only SerpApi solution but it is paid solution so is there any way for get the values? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: requests lib is for http requests not rendering. So as @Jules suggested the need to utilize browser rendering. hard way would be, trace all the requests from the network (tab of dev tool can be one option) and then make each of those requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is good tutotial for Selenium:
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#simple-usage.

I've wrote a short script for you to get started. All you need is to download chromedriver(Chromium) and put it to path. For Windows, chromedriver will have `.exe` resolution

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver')
driver.get("https://www.walmart.com/browse/snacks-cookies-chips/cookies/976759_976787_1001391")
assert "Walmart.com" in driver.title
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".product-title-link.line-clamp.line-clamp-2.truncate-title>span")))

elems = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".product-title-link.line-clamp.line-clamp-2.truncate-title>span")
for el in elems:
    print(el.text)
driver.close()
```

My output:

```
Lance Sandwich Cookies, Nekot Lemon Creme, 8 Ct Box
Nature Valley Biscuits, Almond Butter Breakfast Biscuits w/ Nut Filling, 13.5 oz
Pepperidge Farm Soft Baked Strawberry Cheesecake Cookies, 8.6 oz. Bag
Nutter Butter Family Size Peanut Butter Sandwich Cookies, 16 oz
SnackWell's Devil's Food Cookie Cakes 6.75 oz. Box
Munk Pack Protein Cookies, Variety Pack, Vegan, Gluten Free, Dairy Free Snacks, 6 Count
Great Value Twist & Shout Chocolate Sandwich Cookies, 15.5 Oz.
CHIPS AHOY! Chewy Brownie Filled Chocolate Chip Cookies, 9.5 oz
Nutter Butter Peanut Butter Wafer Cookies, 10.5 oz
Nabisco Sweet Treats Cookie Variety Pack OREO, OREO Golden & CHIPS AHOY!, 30 Snack Packs (2 Cookies Per Pack)
Archway Cookies, Soft Dutch Cocoa, 8.75 oz
OREO Double Stuf Chocolate Sandwich Cookies, Family Size, 20 oz
OREO Chocolate Sandwich Cookies, Party Size, 25.5 oz
Fiber One Soft-Baked Cookies, Chocolate Chunk, 6.6 oz
Nature Valley Toasted Coconut Biscuits with Coconut Filling, 10 ct, 13.5 oz
Great Value Duplex Sandwich Creme Cookies Family Size, 25 Oz
Great Value Assorted Sandwich creme Cookies Family Size, 25 oz
CHIPS AHOY! Original Chocolate Chip Cookies, Family Size, 18.2 oz
Archway Cookies, Crispy Windmill, 9 oz
Nabisco Classic Mix Variety Pack, OREO Mini, CHIPS AHOY! Mini, Nutter Butter Bites, RITZ Bits Cheese, Easter Snacks, 20 Snack Packs
Mother's Original Circus Animal Cookies 11 oz
Lotus Biscoff Cookies, 8.8 Oz.
Archway Cookies, Crispy Gingersnap, 12 oz
Great Value Vanilla Creme Wafer Cookies, 8 oz
Pepperidge Farm Verona Strawberry Thumbprint Cookies, 6.75 oz. Bag
Absolutely Gluten Free Coconut Macaroons
Sheila G's Brownie Brittle GLUTEN-FREE Chocolate Chip Cookie Snack Thins, 4.5oz
CHIPS AHOY! Peanut Butter Cup Chocolate Cookies, Family Size, 14.25 oz
Great Value Lemon Sandwich Creme Cookies Family Size, 25 oz
Keebler Sandies Classic Shortbread Cookies 11.2 oz
Nabisco Cookie Variety Pack, OREO, Nutter Butter, CHIPS AHOY!, 12 Snack Packs
OREO Chocolate Sandwich Cookies, Family Size, 19.1 oz
Lu Petit Ecolier European Dark Chocolate Biscuit Cookies, 45% Cocoa, 5.3 oz
Keebler Sandies Pecan Shortbread Cookies 17.2 oz
CHIPS AHOY! Reeses Peanut Butter Cup Chocolate Chip Cookies, 9.5 oz
Fiber One Soft-Baked Cookies, Oatmeal Raisin, 6 ct, 6.6 oz
OREO Dark Chocolate Crme Chocolate Sandwich Cookies, Family Size, 17 oz
Pinwheels Pure Chocolate & Marshmallow Cookies, 12 oz
Keebler Fudge Stripes Original Cookies 17.3 oz
Pepperidge Farm Classic Collection Cookies, 13.25 oz. Box
```

Comment: thank you for your help. I wanna ask you about the code in order to start well. If I want to get the prices, how can I get ? I didn't understand the `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector` side

Comment: To get a list of prices use css selector: .search-result-gridview-item-wrapper .product-price-with-fulfillment .price-main>.visuallyhidden . `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector` looks for a list of elements with a specified locator

Answer (score 2):

It's because the website is dynamically rendered. So the javascript first need to run before it shows the product. Therefore you need somewhere to run the javascript (bs can't do that) Have a look at the selinium library.